# Rect intersection issues

Tags: c++, opencv, intersection

Using OpenCV 3.1: I have created a simple change detection program. I have added a feature where the user can create constraints on the locations where change will be detected. The user can select ROI's within frame view and change will only be registered within them. I am trying to do this using intersection. Contours are converted to rect's and then the rects are compared to all ROI's user stipulated (if none set program creates a single ROI size of frame). I have seen intersect used but it doesn't want to work for me.

```
tuple<Mat, bool, bool> checkContours(Mat frame, int minArea, vector<vector<Point>> contours, bool occupied, bool initialFrame,vector<Rect> masterROI){
    int foundContourCount;
    Rect boundRect, intersectingRect;
    vector<Rect> boundRectList;
    if (contours.size() > 1){
        foundContourCount = 0;

        //remove all contours with too small an area
        for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
            //get the boundboxes and save the ROI as an Image
            if (contourArea(contours[i]) < minArea){
                continue;
            }
            boundRect = boundingRect( Mat(contours[i]));
            boundRectList.push_back(boundRect);
        }

        //confirm that there are rects in the list
        cout << boundRectList.size() << endl;

        //check if valid bournding areas intersect the provided ROI's
        for(int i = 0; i < masterROI.size();i++){
            for(int ii = 0; i < boundRectList.size();ii++){
                intersectingRect = boundRectList[ii] & masterROI[i];
                if(intersectingRect.area() > 0){
                    //cout << "found one" << endl;
                    rectangle( frame, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, 0 );
                    foundContourCount++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `boundRectList` is not empty, you have infinite loop in this line `for(int ii = 0; i < boundRectList.size();ii++){`,  you did typo, change `i` to `ii`.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks for noting. Been staring at this piece of code for too long now.